# Network sharing on Server 2008 asking for login

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing

I've shared a folder on the root of the C drive and given everyone read access, just as a test. In network sharing center I've disabled password protected sharing.

Whenever I browse to this server from a different machine (\machine) I get prompted for a login. When I try to browse directly to the folder (\machine\public) I also get prompted for a login.

So despite the fact that password protected sharing is disabled it still isn't **allowing anonymous access**.

Suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to access the sharing on Windows Server 2008 computer from Windows XP and Windows 2000, you have to perform the following steps:

1. Change the settings in Network and Sharing Center

Please navigate to Control Panel >>> Network and Sharing Center >> Advanced Sharing Settings, and ensure:

1. Fire Sharing: On;
2. Public folder sharing: Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can open files (or Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can open, change, and create files);
3. Password protected sharing: Turn off password protected sharing
4. Change the security settings in gpedit.msc

Please navigate to gpedit.msc >>> Computer Configuration >>> Security Settings >>> Security Options

Please change Network access: Sharing and security model for local account from “Classic-local users authenticate as themselves” to “Guest only-local users authenticate as Guest”

Answer (score 0):

GPEDIT is only available on the Pro & Ultimate versions of XP, Vista and Win/7.
All HOME/* versions can not use this tool.