# No-password file share still requires login

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing

I'm using a Windows 2008 R2 Server (Workgroup) as file sharing server. Even though `Everyone` has full control (both Share permissions and NTFS permission) to the folder and `Password protected sharing` is on, I still get a login prompt when trying to access the share from another 2008 computer. From a Win7 client it works as expected with no prompt.

What could I have missed?

Comment: your answer is quit fine but first you should enable the Gust Account from the Local Security Policy then it will work

Comment: Thank you Imtiaz, your suggestion pointed me to the final piece to get this working for a client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the "ANONYMOUS" security object is granted access. "EVERYONE" doesn't count.

You also might need to allow anonymous access within group policy.  Open Group Policy Editor and navigate:

```
- Computer Configuration
  - Windows Settings
    - Security Settings
      - Local Policies
        - Security Options.
```

Change “Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users” to Enabled

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I granted access to `ANONYMOUS LOGON` and changed the Security Option in question. I also ran `gpupdate` for good measure, but I still have the same behaviour.

Comment: After reading [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/118368/network-sharing-on-server-2008-asking-for-login/118394#118394) I changed `Network access: Sharing and security model for local account` from “Classic-local users authenticate as themselves” to “Guest only-local users authenticate as Guest”. Now it works.

Comment: @Zano, your recommendation works for me! Thank you!

Comment: @Zano, thanks. This was the missing piece for me. The security policy was reset (somehow); it was driving me up the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Boiled it down to this:

On the file server
Give anonymouse Share and NTFS rights as needed (Read in my case)

Create GPO and apply to file server
Computer - Windows - Security - Local - Security

Accounts:Guest account status - Enabled

Accounts: Rename administrator account - SomeNameOfYourChoise

Accounts: Rename Guest account - SomeNameOfYourChoise

Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously: YourShareName

Network access: Sharing and security model for local account from “Classic-local users authenticate as themselves” to “Guest only-local users authenticate as Guest”.